# Link error using Cygwin toolchain

Tags: c++, android, cygwin

I need to use Cygwin to compile C++ code for an Android project.  I'm having trouble compiling even a basic "hello world" program.  The console gives me this message:

/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.3.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: unrecognized -a option `ware'

I've googled the error and the only result I've found was an issue with one of the programs (I think it was binutils) being out of date, and was resolved when that program was updated.  I downloaded the entirety of the Cygwin package at once, so I don't think that's the problem.  The compiler and linker aren't communicating properly.  How do I fix it without changing compilers?

Comment: Show us the command lines being used.

Comment: $ g++ -f $ANDROID/build/core/build-local.mk

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - Android doesn't support the standard C++ library.  Fixed by downloading http://www.crystax.net/android/ndk-r4.php

Which basically reimplements that for Android.